# get Some(): Todo[] {} - Is it some kinde of Shorthand Technique?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

In the tutorial about services in Angular, I found a piece of code.

```
getTodos(): Todo[] {
  return [
    { name: "Todo 1", status: TodoStatus.BUG },
    { name: "Todo 2", status: TodoStatus.TODO },
    { name: "Todo 3", status: TodoStatus.IN_REVIEW },
  ]
}
```

The author writes that it is a method that returns the initial elements of the list. On the left side of the colon is the name of the method. I don't understand what is happening on the right side. What is the role of Todo[] which is an empty array. What is the meaning of []{}?  Could someone please explain this to me? Thank you.

Comment: You add the `typescript` tag, but apparently never saw a type annotation before. [Function Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#function-types). Post-edit: no, the tag was completely correct.

Comment: It's a return type using a typescript interface. Todo[] means the function will return an [] (Array) of Todo Types, hence Todo[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's only look at the first line.

```
getTodos(): Todo[] {
```

It declares a function named `getTodos` and what it returns: `Todo[]`.
The bracket is just the start of the implementation of the function.
The benefit of declaring the return type is is that the compiler knows when the function does not return that type. For example, if the function only returned an array of integers, the compiler won't work, preventing a possible runtime error. This is where typescript shines.

You might wonder which type a function has if it doesn't return anything. (None or empty return statement.

```
doStuff() : void {
 // I dont return anything*.
}
```

Now lets say we have a function that removes the last element of an array and returns that element. We could declare it as :

```
removeLastElementOfArray(array: any[]): any {
    return array.pop();
}
```

It might we obvious to us that, given an array of numbers as argument to this function, the function would return a number. However we annotated the return type with any, so the typescript compiler has no idea that there is a relation between the types in the array and the return type.

For this we have generics:

```
 removeLastElementOfArray<T>(array: T[]): T {
    return array.pop();
}
```

Now the typescript compiler know that if we given an array of strings, the function will return a string. Same goes for any other type. Generics are very powerful that you should as much as possible to prevent the use of any.

*Technically in JS, functions without return statements return undefined, but we annotate them with 'void', because that's how those type of functions are defined in typed languages.

Comment: Nice detailed answer, now everything is clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`: Todo[]` is a typescript annotation (interface, type) and declares return type to `getTodos()` method in the same way as other type oriented programming languages (C#, Java, etc.).

In your specific example it means that your method can return array of objects that are type of `Todo`.

Types are not obligatory so your code would work the same without declaring return type to the method.

```
getTodos() {
  return [
    { name: "Todo 1", status: TodoStatus.BUG },
    { name: "Todo 2", status: TodoStatus.TODO },
    { name: "Todo 3", status: TodoStatus.IN_REVIEW },
  ]
}
```

Comment: It looks better now. Thank you.